# Arch Linux Installer - Scroll back in terminal

Tags: linux, arch-linux, terminal, system-installation, scrolling

Is it possible to scroll back in the terminal available in Arch Linux?

I'm running a script and would like to read what appeared before.
I know I can use `| more`, but in my specific case I can't use it because the screen is filled with ASCII menus that overwrite all characters on screen.

Answer (score 7):

If <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> don't work there's nothing you can do. Scrollback has been recently removed from the Linux kernel due to [security issues](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.9-Drops-Soft-Scrollback).

Comment: That's why it's not working then. I will try to use `script` command then.

Comment: security issues are good but how can i see output that out of screen? %$#%$^#%$#%

Comment: @Igor `tmux`/`screen` but they are both crappy "semi-solutions" to a systemic issue. How are you supposed to use them for e.g. boot? or installing a system?

Comment: Many thanks for the link! However, they don't say anything about security there, only that code rots and is unmaintained. It's a very sad decision for me.

Answer (score 1):

If [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) is an option you can always read its buffer.